# Trace.TraceError not writing any log while using minlevel="Error"

Tags: c#, nlog, system.diagnostics

I am trying to route all my `diagnostics` output to a file using `NLog`.

Below is my `diagnostics` configuration,

```xml
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
  <listeners>
    <add name="Test" type="NLog.NLogTraceListener, NLog" />
    <remove name="Default" />
  </listeners>
</trace>
```

and NLog Rule Config,

```xml
<logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="logfile" />
```

C# Code,

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("test");
```

If I change my rule `minlevel="Error"` to `minlevel="Trace"`, then output is writing.

Question, with setting `minlevel="Error"`, why this is not writing?

Comment: because maybe nowhere in the application a log entry on the level Error is created?

Comment: it's created, if I change to level to `Trace`, I can see the data

Comment: Yes, but with "Trace" you get all entries, with "Error" only those that have the level "Error". Check if there is any entry with level "Error" in the log file captured with level "Trace", if not everything is running correctly.

Comment: @Noren, the level is `Error` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logs are probably not written on the Error level,

You could log on what level the logs are logged by using `${level}`,

e.g.

```xml
<target type="file" name="logfile" layout="${level} ${message} ${exception}">
```

and

```xml
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
```

Comment: Thanks Julian, I enabled level, it's shows `2018-07-18 21:02:26.6702 Error`

Comment: using C# code `System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("test");` for writing `Error` trace

Comment: Thanks, now it's coming for me.